# Como cambio valores de celdas en un rango con un formula "Si"

Tags: excel, formulas

Quiero cambiar los 'valores' las celdas `I13` hasta la `K13`, es decir `I13 J13 K13` por medio de la formula "Si" cuando el valor sea verdadero.

Comment: No está del todo clara la pregunta porque no se incluye un ejemplo de datos de entrada y los resultados esperados. Por otro lado, falta mencionar lo que se ha buscado/investigado sobre el tema. De todas formas te dejé una respuesta, así que ya tienes dos. Sería bueno que aceptaras una de ellas o bien dejaras comentarios si es que no fueron claras.

Answer (score 1):

Para cambiar los valores de celdas contiguas con una única fórmula, usa fórmula de matriz.

Por ejemplo, para comparar los valores de F3, G3 y H3 con 1. Si son iguales, regresa un 1 en la celda I3,J3 y K3 según corresponda, hacer los siguiente:

1. Seleccionar I3:K3
2. Escribir =IF(F3:H3=1,1,0) y oprimir <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Intro</kbd>

**Referencias**

- [Crear una fórmula de matriz](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Crear-una-f%C3%B3rmula-de-matriz-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d)

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar los valores de dichas celdas tienes que compararlo con otra celda.

Por ejemplo, imagina que en la celda A1 tienes el valor 1, la celda B1 será verdadero o falso si A1 es 1.

```
=SI(A1=1;VERDADERO;FALSO)
```

B1 devolverá `VERDADERO`, si la función la colocas en la celda B1

Tendrías que indicar qué es lo que vas a evaluar. Recuerda la función `SI (IF)` necesita evaluar un parámetro de entrada para devolver un booleano. Puede devolver lo que tu necesites (texto, número, boolean, etc.)

```
=SI(CELDA A COMPARAR; VERDADERO; FALSO)
```

En programación es lo mismo,

```
Si (parametro es verdadero) entonces

#código

sino

#código

Fin
```